# web server installation before ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu

it might be a trivial question, nevertheless... Is it supposed that a web server (say, Apache) should be installed in order to make Ruby on Rails installation? What about database?
If yes, could you advice specific programs? I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, Ruby is 1.9.3.p392 and Rails is 3.2.12.

Comment: Are there no installation guides for Rails on Ubuntu? That seems hard to believe.

Comment: there is a huge amount of such guides. Most of then of them do not mention neither Apache nor any other web server. I followed that guides but my Rails did not work properly, therefore I was curious whether some web server (along with database support) was supposed to be preinstalled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your task.  You can use Rails with [Webrick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WEBrick) as HTTP-server (for development), which is installed with Rails and you can use Sqlite as database which you need install separately.

[Here](http://excid3.com/blog/setting-up-rails-on-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal-with-ruby-node-js-nginx-passenger-and-mysql-or-postgres/#.UTjUVqVUp-U) is a guide which can helps you.